# Multilingual site in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, localization, codeigniter-3, multilingual

I just finished reading the user guide of Codeigniter 3.
I did not find anything about the locale (In other frameworks the locale is used in the URL and then the framework takes care of using the translations of the current locale ...).

Is there any best practice way for creating multilingual websites with Codeigniter 3?

I will be using 'en' and 'fr'.

The answer that I posted below solves only half of the problem, because now, to be able to use 'fr' and 'en' links in the header template I have to add this in the controller:

```
  $data['urls'] = array(
     'en' => base_url('en/news'),
     'fr' => base_url('fr/nouvelles'),
  );
```

ANd I have to do it for new methods that add.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here are my findings so far:

Here are my routes:

```
$route['en/news'] = 'news';
$route['fr/nouvelles'] = 'news';
```

In my news controller I have the following:

```
class News extends CI_Controller {

   public function __construct() {
      parent::__construct();
      $this->load->model('newsModel');
      $this->load->helper('url_helper');
      $this->lang->load('news', strtok(uri_string(), '/'));
   }

   public function index() {

      echo $this->lang->line('news');
      exit;
   }
}
```

Of course you need to add the translations files.
Please do not hesitate to suggest improvements.

Thanks